# How to map embedded interaction of a SVG to Qt?

Tags: qt, svg, interactive

Is it possible to access interactions defined in an SVG file using Qt?
this would be a huge help in creating beautiful, interactive graphical widgets

Comment: Not much honestly, clearly Qt works fine with Svg, but I haven't seen / found any API calls to access interactive aspects. So I'm wondering whether Qt supports this out of the box, or whether projects exist that support this functionality.

Comment: Could this question help? [Integration of Svg and Javascript in qt application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586437/integration-of-svg-and-javascript-in-qt-application)

Comment: Ah, I've come across that reference too, thanks. But its not of practical value: what I'm looking for is a way to create slider, knobs, buttons, lots of small graphical widgets.

Comment: Some minor grammatical improvements

Comment: Qt SVG support is pretty basic. If you want to create beautiful interactive graphical widgets, I think the answer is [Qt Quick](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-index.html) and [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html).