# Display SVG image in QtWebView with the right size

Tags: python, svg, pyqt, qtwebkit, qtwebview

I'm trying to display some Wikipedia articles containing math in `SVG` images
in QtWebView, though I can't figure out how to set `width` and `height` attributes of the image. `QtWebView` will ignore these attributes and when I
omit them the image is very small.

You can test it as follows:
Download [this](https://github.com/gen2brain/pyhtmleditor) HTML editor.
Go to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra) web page and download e.g. [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e15d3619d42b28662c5952c9ece60cd928e31774) SVG image.

Create img element, reflecting the styling in Wikipedia:

```
<img src="e15d3619d42b28662c5952c9ece60cd928e31774.svg" style="vertical-align: -0.671ex; width:25.517ex; height:2.343ex;">
```

And the image will be ignored.

The following works, but the image is very small.

```
<img src="e15d3619d42b28662c5952c9ece60cd928e31774.svg" >
```

How to display the image with the right size (width and height)?

Comment: Why is `python` tagged?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans The editor is `pyhtmleditor` using `PyQT`, so it's written in Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this HTML approach for changing an SVG image dimensions:

```
<!-- you can test this code in any online html editor. -->

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- blah blah blah... -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>all the images must be redrawn properly when SVG animation runs...</p>
        <img height="250px" width="800px" border="5" src="https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e15d3619d42b28662c5952c9ece60cd928e31774">
    </body>
</html>
```

Very often SVG height or width are incorrectly calculated in WebKit browsers. To solve this problem use this CSS style:

```
svg { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

I've recently found quite useful and interesting post: [CSS Tricks: How to Scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/).

Or try this Python approach for changing an SVG image dimensions described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016050/pyqt-with-interactive-svg-images).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QGraphicsWebView
import sys

application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myScene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
myView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(myScene)
box = QtSvg.QGraphicsSvgItem('/Users/swift/Desktop/myImage.svg').boundingRect()
webView = QGraphicsWebView()
webView.load(QtCore.QUrl('/Users/swift/Desktop/myImage.svg'))
webView.setFlags(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemClipsToShape)
webView.resize(box.width(), box.height())

incWidth = 48
incHeight = 36
myScene.addItem(webView)
myView.resize(box.width() + incWidth, box.height() + incHeight)
myView.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And, of course, you can call `setHtml()` public function with argument:

```
code = 
       """
       <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>

       <!-- You can load SVG image itself. -->
       <img height="250px" width="800px" style="width: 100%;" src="myImage.svg">

       <!-- Or you can load SVG Viewport and use other images inside it. -->
       <svg width="600" height="450">
       <image href="myImage.svg" x="0" y="0" height="320px" width="240px"/>
       </svg>

       </body>
       </html> 
       """

self.webView.setHtml(code)
```

Or assign the size directly via Qt:

```
svgImage = QImage(QSize(1280, 720))
```

Also look at official `Qt SVG Documentation` describing XML-based approach [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsvg-index.html).

Comment: I'd like to change the dimensions in HTML code. e.g. the application has a call `self.webView.setHtml("<p></p>")` for initial HTML. Assume I won't be changing application code, but only import HTML file into it (programatically), with the images. SVG images are making trouble, so I'd like to convert `width` and `height` to something that looks nice in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use other units for height and width. For example:

```
<img src="https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg" height='200px' />
```

Comment: How did you inserted it? When I paste it with `Edit` -> `Insert HTML` it will ignore the code.

Comment: Can you try with the above image ?

Comment: I tried, but it ignores the inserted HTML (<img ... />)